# What anime is this girl with pink hair on a key chain from?

Tags: merchandise

I'm wondering what anime this character is from?
She's so cute that I just bought it anyway but I feel silly not knowing if anyone asks me about it. I would be very happy to know.

Thank you!

[image: anime girl keychain]

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:madoka-magica]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That keychain is actually [Meruru](http://myanimelist.net/character/37596/Meruru/pictures) from [Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8769/Ore_no_Imouto_ga_Konnani_Kawaii_Wake_ga_Nai).

[image]

But it's totally understandable to mistaken it as [Madoka](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9756/Mahou_Shoujo_Madoka%E2%98%85Magica) at first glance.

Comment: In the interest of being pointlessly pedantic, I'd like to note that the gif in the post is actually the character Kanako cosplaying as Meruru, which is why the eye color differs from the keychain.